# Uploading file to AWS S3 with React

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 based on this tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

I copied the html form and changed "Base64-encoded policy string", "signature-value" to my values, as well as changed X-Amz-Date from 2015 to 2019 and in 'http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/' I replaced sigv4examplebucket with my bucket.

On server side (node.js) I call `Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(policy))` on policy object and create a signature with this code:

```
var kDate = crypto.HmacSHA256("20190830T120000Z", "AWS4" + "MY_KEY");
var kRegion = crypto.HmacSHA256("us-east-1", kDate);
var kService = crypto.HmacSHA256("s3", kRegion);
var kSigning = crypto.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
return kSigning;
```

The problem is that my website gives me an error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Is there a way to find where is the problem?

Also, I didn't change anything in my basket on AWS S3. Should I add some policy there or something?

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, but I'd recommend just using the `aws-sdk` package for node (from Amazon), as there are methods to create these signatures properly. (unless of course you can't use that package for some reason, then disregard)

Comment: Can you send me link or code for creating the signature with this aws-sdk?

Comment: This is the method you want: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property

Comment: It worked. That is much better way to do it. Thank you